# SSIS is hanging during Update with 3 millions of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, ssis

I'm implementing a new method for a warehouse. The new method consist on perform incremental loading between source and destination tables (Insert,Update or Delete).

All the table are working really well, except for 1 table which the Source has more than 3 millions of rows, as you will see in the image below it just start running but never finish.
Probable I'm not doing the update in the correct way or there is another way to do it.

Here are some pictures of my SSIS package:
[image: ControlFlow]

Highlighted object is where it hangs. 
[image: DataFlow]
This is the stored procedure I call to update the table:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateDim_A] 
      @ID INT,
      @FileDataID INT
     ,@CategoryID SMALLINT
     ,@FirstName VARCHAR(50)
     ,@LastName VARCHAR(50)
     ,@Company VARCHAR(100)
     ,@Email VARCHAR(250) AS BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;


BEGIN TRAN 
 UPDATE DIM_A 
    SET                  
        [FileDataID] = @FileDataID,
        [CategoryID] = @CategoryID,
        [FirstName]  = @FirstName,
        [LastName]   = @LastName,
        [Company]    = @Company,
        [Email]      = @Email

    WHERE PartyID=@ID

    COMMIT TRAN;  END
```

**Note:**
I already tried Dropping the constraint and indexes and changing the recovery mode of the database to simple.

Any help will be appreciate.

---

**After Apply the solution provided by @Prabhat G, this is how my package looks like, running in 39 seconds (avg)!!!**

[image: fIXED5]

Inside Dim_A DataFlow
[image]

Comment: This is actually the slowest possible way of doing what you're doing. Sorts... single row updates. Everytime I open someone else's package and see this I groan. Load the data into a staging table and do a single update. Don't do it the way you are doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow these 2 performance enhancers and you'll avoid your bottleneck.

1. Remove `sort` transformation. In your source, while fetching the data use `order by` sql. **Reason** being, `sort` takes up all the records in memory before sorting. You don't want that, be it incremental or full load.
2. In the last step of update, introduce another Staging Table instead of `update records oledb command`, which will be replica of Dim table. Once all the matching records are inserted in this new staging table, exit the Data flow task and create `EXECUTE SQL TASK` which will simply UPDATE Dim table based on joining ID/conditions.

**Reason** for this is, oledb command hits row by row. Always prefer update using `Execute SQL Task` as its a batch process.

---

**Edit:**
As per comments, to update only changed rows in `Execute SQL Task`, add the conditions in where clause:

```
eg:

UPDATE x
SET
   x.attribute_A = y.attribute_A
  ,x.attribute_B = y.attribute_B
FROM
DimA x
 inner join stg_DimA y
ON x.Id = y.Id
WHERE
(x.Attribute_A <> y.Attribute_A
OR x.Attribute_B <> y.Attribute_B)
```

Comment: This is the best workaround I've seen. Works like a charm. Thank you!!

Comment: I will post the pictures of how it looks now.

Comment: @JCACERES For an added performance boost, you should consider only placing records that need to be updated into the staging table (see my answer for details). Not only does it speed things up by reducing the size of the transaction, but the should reduce index fragmentation caused by updates and the overall transaction log.

Comment: @JCACERES : Glad to help :-) Check my updated answer. It covers J Weezy's method

Comment: I'll try that, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So your problem is actually very simple the method you are using is executing that stored procedure for every row returned. If you have 9961(as in your picture) rows to update it will run that statement 9961 sepreate time. Chances are if you are to look at active queries running on SQL server you'll see that procedure executing over and over.

What you should do to speed this up is dump that data into a staging table then use the execute SQL task further in your package to run a standard SQL update. This will run much faster.

Comment: If I do that I will loose the lookup object which is the one that compare the source and destination.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. What I'm suggesting here is that instead of running that update. You take all of those values at the spot of that data flow and insert it into a table you're staging. You can keep any values you had in the dataflow. Then once that's staged you can run the update. It runs much faster than the method you are currently using.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to execute a stored procedure within the data flow. The correct SqlCommand will be an explicit UPDATE query and then map the columns from SSIS to the columns on the table that you are updating.

```
UPDATE DIM_A 
SET FileDataID = ?
    ,CategoryID = ?
    ,FirstName = ?
    ,LastName = ?
    ,Company = ?
    ,Email = ?
WHERE PartyID = ?
```

Note: The @Id needs to be included as a column in your data flow.

One final thing you should consider, as Zane correctly pointed out: you should only update rows that have changed. So, in your data flow you should add a Conditional Split transformation that checks to see if any of the columns in the new source row are different from the existing table rows. Only rows that are different should be send to the OLE DB Command - the rest can be disregarded.

Comment: Yes, I'm already doing that, I will upload the image of the mapping.

Comment: YOU CANNOT CALL A STORED PROCEDURE IN A OLE DB COMMAND IN ORDER TO UPDATE A TABLE. You need to move the update script contained in your stored proc and place that in the SqlCommand.

Comment: If using this method it's still quite likely to run very slowly since it will be a row by row update.

Comment: @Zane No doubt, OLE DB Commands are slow. JCACERES should have a split transformation to only send those rows from the source that are different from the existing row. There is no need to update existing rows that have not changed.